# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, beta-progress, top-7, design

What should our logo and site design look like?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this topic up! It's always good to get an early start on design discussions.

Comment: Excellent question, however, asking a bunch of developers for design advice seems like a bad idea. I imagine most of us, myself included, can't design for shit. That being said, I do really like PleaseStand's logo idea.

Comment: wow, I just realized how old this thread was. Thought it was odd that it got so much attention so quickly... Either way, it was a good question.

Comment: @mseancole Only because we develope, doesn't mean we can't design. ;)

Comment: There should be a dark skin for the site in my opinion. Much easier on the eyes!

Comment: I think that we should keep the Beta-Blue. (In some way). It's been around so long that it seems like a symbol of CR to me.

Answer (score 40):

I looked through the [major SE sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) and their logos and noticed they're quite minimalistic. So I grabbed my sketch blog and a pen. This is what I came up with:

[image: CR Magnifier 1]

### Update 1

- No more beta-blue
- Better *angles* for the breaks, so people actually figure out what the letters may be. :~)

[image: CR Magnifier 2]

### Update 2

Based retailcoder's [T-Shirt question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/1000-days-in-beta-lets-make-cr-t-shirts)

[image: CR "Approved" logo]

### Update 3

Another [T-Shirt question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/1000-days-in-beta-lets-make-cr-t-shirts) based thing

[image: CR "i <3 CR" logo]

### Update 4

As requested by [Bobby](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2612/bobby), being pretty obvious:

[image: CR "Code Review" logo]

**Just playing around with more abstract drafts**

[image: CR "Code" abstract logo]

Comment: That magnifying glass looks like "CR"!

Comment: I like the idea of a stylized magnifying class...would it be possible to put it into "Code Review"?

Comment: I asked because I think that keeping the name of the site would be beneficial and I'd really like to see if it can fit into the text "Code Review" (I'm unsure because of the "d"). The good thing is, the lens can be used to "mark" anything that comes out of Code Review (like you said the Weekend challenges).

Comment: @Bobby You mean something like "C[q]de Review" (with [q] being the magnifier)? I also thought about making a variatione where "Code" is written as the lense. The "C" and "O" are visible, the "D" is there as well, just the "E" would need something extra.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea. Your idea also sounds interesting.

Comment: @Bobby See my latest edit. Hope you like it.

Comment: Yes, I like it. That's exactly what I meant. I think that's awesome, very well done.

Comment: There may be a way to make the "CR" more obvious: remove "Review" from the first line, and add "eview" on the second line. Possibly remove the initial 'C', and add a circle (i.e. 'O') inside the magnifying glass.

Comment: @ChrisW Thank you for the suggestions. I tried adding an 'o' or circle inside the magnifying glass, but that kind of ruined the original idea of my logo. I try it again and maybe add something to the answer. :)

Comment: Maybe if the 'O' were the same font size as "DE", then the 'C' and 'R' could be bigger (than all the other letters). I don't think it will necessarily work as an idea; just an off-the-wall idea. The R will make the kerning between the O and the D look awkward (bigger than the kerning between the D and E).

Comment: @ChrisW Yep, getting a _working_ kerning is a bit tricky. I don't want to change the angle of the handle. I'll find some time on the weekend. You can ping me in the chat, if you want to discuss.

Comment: Bye bye beta blue.

Comment: I personally like the second but last Image the best. It might look even better with the 'v' of review changed to a majuscle lambda: "Code ReΛiew", also in orange ;)

Comment: In the last one, how would it look with eview added after the R embedded in the o?  I'm thinking that it would be underneath the DE.

Comment: @Brythan Yeah, possibly. Currently I don't have much time on my hands to redo some of these. If there are more requests I surely will find some spare time, though. :)

Comment: I really love these. A lot. But taking a second look, do we really want to use orange & gray? It reminds me of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RubberDuck There is nothing really that stops us from using a different color palette. No problem. Do we already have an opinion here?

Comment: It doesn't seem that we do @kleinfreund. I'll poke around meta and see if I find anything. If I don't, I'll post one.

Comment: @kleinfreund - just "closing the loop" (pun intended), you seen [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/new-design-branding-for-code-review)?

Answer (score 15):

A magnifying glass on top of some bad code?

[image: Code review logo with "wooden" magnifying glass]

If anyone is wondering, the code behind the magnifying glass is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {int n=101, x; for(x=0;++x<n;)
printf(!(x % 15) ? "FizzBuzz\n" : !(x %
3) ? "Fizz\n" : !(x % 5) ? "Buzz\n" : "%d
\n", x); return 0;}
```

Comment: +1 this one's pretty good too. idealmachine has a similar idea to mine

Comment: May be good to have green writing on a dark background. with this general idea.

Comment: Don't like the sound of green, maybe some kind of stylish syntax highlighting, and a different colour for the top layer of text.

Comment: @Wes, Physics.SE had a dark background for a while and had to revert due to usability issues. I visited a few times while they had the dark background and found it to be a strain on the eyes. I would prefer Code Review not go down that path.

Comment: @idealmachine: Posted feedback to the use of a "magnifying glass" as visual icon within my answer here: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like/258#258

Comment: +1 @Brian Reichle: Agree, black is bad as a background.

Comment: I really like this idea, but the magnifying glass looks a little awkward. The handle seems skewed and is too long for the size of the lens. BTW: Is that a fisheye effect for the "lens" or are my eyes deceiving me? If it is, that's a nice touch, if not then that's a great illusion.

Comment: I like this logo, but also think the `codeReview();` should be replaced with something more OOP (I know, it's a bias), but how about `code.review();` as suggested by @retailcoder here: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1209/31503

Comment: Great code! Very readable and clean. Maybe replace the magic number in `x % 15` with `x % (3 * 5)` to make it perfect.

Answer (score 12):

I kind of like the idea of a pseudocode block being worked into the logo somehow. Something like this:

[image: Code Review Example Logos]

EDIT: See below.

[image]

I don't know how to feel about the magnifying glass, but I included it just for fun.

Comment: +1 @65Fbef05: For being a real logo, very cool. It's not clear if that's one logo, or three versions of a logo. The abstract blocks for text are nice, but in my opinion could be clustered a little more to make it more of a stand alone icon.

Comment: It's three versions - I wanted to see what it would look like in different colors. Are you thinking more clustered as in equal x and y dimensions (ie. a square instead of a rectangle)?

Comment: I really like the bottom one in your edit, the magnifying glass is a really nice touch.

Answer (score 12):

I'm thinking of a more sober design, something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

First of all I really like [kleinfreund](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/35408/kleinfreund)'s magnifying glass idea. However I think, that as programmers.SE has a logo that is not that serious, even a little funny, the coffee mug, the same could apply to codereview.SE.

So what do you think about the famous code reviewing [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

[image: Rubber Duck]

I am by no means a graphics designer, so please evaluate this only as an idea, and not as a final logo suggestion :)

Comment: I love it! (But am admittedly biased...)

Comment: [Biased as well](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/master/README.md), but yeah, absolutely - this is an awesome idea!

Comment: Looks good.  Go for it.

Comment: Love it! Just not as the logo for CR...

Comment: I like the idea, but to me rubber duck says *"debugging"*, not *"review"*, and the former is definitively not on-topic; this could lead to confusion.

Answer (score 9):

## Colors

I may get lynched for this, but "beta blue" has become part of our identity after being in beta for so long. I personally like the the idea of keeping just a splash of it around. It shouldn't be the primary color, but it would be a nice accent.

[I really like some of the logos kleinfreund came up with](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1462/41243), but gray and orange are StackOverflow's colors. We've very little in common with SO and I don't think we should be using their colors.

### BlockQuotes

Please, please, please, leave blockquote formatting alone. StackOverflow and Meta's blockquotes don't differentiate enough between a code block inside of a blockquote and a regular code block. The yellow background on Code Review's makes it very easy to visually tell the difference. It doesn't have to be yellow, but the background should be a differnt color.

**StackOverflow:**

[image: SO code block vs blockquote]

**Code Review:**

[image: CR code block vs blockquote]

**Update 1/20/15:**

As of 1/16/15 or so, [it looks like SO no longer has the gray on gray quote blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270612/3198973), so hopefully we don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Won't every beta site have the same feeling of connection to the beta blue?

Comment: Sure @nhgrif. Probably, but how many spend 3+ years with the beta blue? I don't think it should be the primary color. Just an accent.

Answer (score 9):

### Code block formatting

@JeroenVannevel [posted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18420363#18420363) in The 2nd Monitor a screen capture from someone's IDE and code that I think looks really sharp and sexy, and makes code reading easier on the eyes:

[image: JeroenScreenCap]

Or maybe at least make it look like one of the popular IDEs (Visual Studio shown):

[image: visualstudio]

Compare to our current code blocks:

[image: CRcodeblock]

That brown-turquoise-on-grey just isn't very attractive. Would it be possible to *prettify* our code blocks a bit as such?

**Edit 2014-10-31**

[Stack Exchange Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242889/code-block-prettify-for-code-review-after-graduation)

[Google Prettify (default) CSS source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.css)

[Prettify themes gallery](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles/index.html)

[SO answer on making code block look like Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2171410/3626537)

Comment: Well, stack exchange uses [google prettify](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2492/41243), so I would think [these themes](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles/index.html) are available. Desert looks pretty close to what you've shared. I'm a fan of this.

Answer (score 8):

I had some free time (No actually it's 2:56 AM, way past my bed time).
So I whipped this up (Not a logo,but a wallpaper).

btw I'm not a graphic designer. But I know how to Google. :D

### Download

[PSD and 1920x1080 PNGs](http://pc.cd/ne1)

### Preview

#### Version 1

[image: Version 1]

#### Version 2

[image: Version 2]

#### Version 3

[image: Version 3]

**PS : See if you can find your username in there.**

Comment: Feel free to post suggestions

Answer (score 7):

I came up with this basic idea and thought I would raise the topic myself, clearly everyone else is way ahead of me :)

[image: Suggested Logo]

[image: Alternative]

Comment: has to say "WTF" though :)

Comment: @Jeff Artwood: I just thought it would be nice to put the site name in the logo, but I suppose we could call the site wtf.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: +1 "WTF!" ...mainly just because it's super funny, and gets away from the "dry" nature of peer review in most places.

Comment: +1 @Brian Reichle I really like the idea of a new site at wtf.stackexchange.com - could be a catch all for migrating aneurism-inducing posts.

Answer (score 7):

**BACKGROUND:** I've designed easily 2000+ logos; meaning paid, not on my free time.

Have a few ideas, but my suggestion would be to focus on and agree on the "feel" the logo should have, and the message that it's sending.

**FEEL:** Techie, Fresh, ...

**MESSAGE:** Dialog, Community, Code, Clear

**VISUAL:** In terms of a visual, I image comments bubble "talking" to each other and/or point to a block code of lines that appears to be text.

**FEEDBACK:**

1. A "**magnify glass**" is old school, and may come off as being overly critical, singular, and a closed loop form of analysis.
2. "**Glasses**" might appear weak, and are also old school.

Answer (score 6):

Two people crouched over a computer... silhouette style.

Comment: it's so ... romantic! *swoons*

Comment: silhouettes usually don't have a modern feel to them, though agree it's topic as a message and visual,

Answer (score 6):

> ```
>           _____                    _____          
>          /\    \                  /\    \         
>         /::\    \                /::\    \        
>        /::::\    \              /::::\    \       
>       /Python\    \            /Scala:\    \      
>      /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \     
>     /:::/  \:::\    \        /:::/__\:::\    \    
>    /:::/    \:::\    \      /Ruby\   \:::\    \   
>   /:::/    / \:::\    \    /::::::\   \:::\    \  
>  /:::/    /   \:::\    \  /:::/\:::\   \:::\____\ 
> /dot/____/     \net\____\/:::/  \:::\   \:::|    |
> \:::\    \      \::/    /\::/   |Java\  /:::|____|
>  \:::\    \      \/____/  \/____|:::::\/:::/    / 
>   \:::\    \                    |:::::::::/    /  
>    \VBA\    \                   |::|\C++:/    /   
>     \:::\    \                  |::| \::/____/    
>      \PHP\    \                 |::|  ~|          
>       \:::\    \                |::|   |          
>        \:::\____\               \::|   |          
>         \C#/    /                \:|   |          
>          \/____/                  \|___|
> ```

Add/remove the languages if you prefer.

Comment: I don't think "Brainfuck" will fit...

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg it does.. directly above C++

Comment: yeah, let's just put a big swear word in our logo and get blocked by all sorts of website filters.   wait a second, no let's not do that.

Comment: **HOLY CARP**!! You're an ASCII art ninja!!

Comment: @Mat'sMug not really, pretty good sites for ;)

Comment: `dot____net`: `.net` peeps, where is your deity now :p

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a yellow highlighter pen? It suggests syntax highlighting and focus... I find the glasses metaphor a little long in the tooth :)

Comment: I'd like that for a favicon.

Comment: +1 @pat: re: "glasses metaphor [is] little long in the tooth (that being, out dated)"... I completely agree. As for the "yellow highlighter pen", that says focus to me -- which while related to peer review, likely does not send a complete and/or clear message. For additional info, see my answer: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like/258#258 Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

First image that pops up in my mind when I hear `code review` is this:

[image: Code-review facepalm]

P.S.: I know the image itself is not that suitable for the logo, but I wanted to share the idea.

Comment: This is not a positive message. It'd be like having a fat person as the icon for a fast food place, not the message you want to send... or at least in my opinion. That said, the image is on topic, and does speak to the idea of code review. Cheers!

Comment: I both like the idea and agree with blunders... :-)

Answer (score 1):

When I think of a code review, I think of a meeting room and a projector. I have absolutely no idea how that could be conveyed in a web site design, but just throwing that out there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking LOC's(lines of code) with glasses over them. Something like this:
[image]

Comment: this make me think on matrix

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the letters CR, or 'Code Review' with the CR letters artfully accentuated with editing [beziers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)

Here are some examples of the style

1. http://www.farinhansford.com/dianne/images/font-design-a.jpg
2. http://creativeroots.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Arabic-font-design9.png

Answer (score 0):

I think of LOC. Notepads with LOCs on 'em.

Answer (score -2):

A good logo would be a group of people's shadow outline with their backs turned towards the viewers(us) and a colored in guy showing his code to the anonymous crowd.