# Call of Duty II - We're still on a mission

Tags: discussion, voting, unanswered-questions

## Briefing.

November 16, 2013. In response to a not-so-shiny [Stack Exchange Community Managers' review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/991) of our favorite Stack Exchange site and seeing that about 10% of the site's content consisted of [zombified posts](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1510/23788), the Mug formerly known as retailcoder invited the then-tiny CR community to [counter the zombie invasion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/999/23788). How? By **answering unanswered questions** and, equally important, by **voting**.

**And we succeeded**, with numbers to back it up: from 88% answered, CR went up to 96% and stabilized at or around 95% for pretty much a whole year now, and in the mean time [**we had our long, long-awaited graduation announcement**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2545/23788) - what more could we ask for?

**95% answered is something to be proud of**. But Code Review has literally [doubled in size since September 2013](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/832/23788), and that means the missing 5% is, in absolute figures, pretty much exactly the same amount of zombifying questions as the missing 10% we had back then: a whole army of **a thousand zombies** is walking - and growing every day:

[image: steep, VERY steep increase of walking zombies in the past few months]

The number of *Quick Answers* per week has dramatically improved, and that's thoroughly awesome. But the light blue-ish purple series ("10's of Zombies Still Walking") is what we're looking at. That trend cannot be allowed to keep going, ***we must do something!***

---

### Great, let's do something. But *what* exactly?

Simple. Kill zombies. If every single *avid user* (per Area51's standards, users with > 200 reputation - that's 2,088 users) shot a zombie tonight, they'd be exterminated.

1. **Fire at will.** Most zombies are easy to take down: all they need is an **upvoted answer**. [**Find your zombie here**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes).
2. **VOTE.** Is your profile on [this page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=week)? Don't just pile-up-vote on the hot questions and great answers; look for zombie-killers - good answers without upvotes on old questions. Votes are your ammunitions, and you get 40 per day, everyday. Spend them!
3. **Have FUN!** Reviewing code is fun all by itself, but there's more: join the regulars in [**The 2nd Monitor**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595), earn imaginary Internet points, badges, race someone to the next privilege level, or better, race someone to collecting 10 [Necromancer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer) badges as fast as possible!

Any ideas on what else we can do as individuals? As a community?

---

> **2015-03-13** (ooh, Friday 13th!) - **\$1,187\$** walking zombies at the time of this writing. The highest registered zombie population ever.

Last week:

- \$170\$ incoming zombies (new questions asked) | \$24.3\$ per day
- \$286\$ answers given | \$40.9\$ per day
- \$1,252\$ answer votes spent | \$178.9\$ per day (~4.5 users running dry on ammo)

> **2015-03-27** - **\$1,240\$** zombies...

Last 2 weeks:

- \$365\$ incoming zombies (new questions asked) | \$26.1\$ per day
- \$531\$ answers given | \$37.9\$ per day
- \$1,187+365-531 = 312\$ zombies down | \$22.3\$ per day (+3.8 zombies daily)
- \$2,054\$ answer votes spent | \$146.7\$ per day (~3.7 users running dry on ammo)

Comment: Anyone looking for good answers to vote on should feel free to peruse the [tag:objective-c] and [tag:swift] questions, which typically just have me to keep them company.

Comment: There's also this: http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/265223/forgotten-zombie-killers -- 133 zombies with answers but without votes, *potentially* (but not necessarily) ripe for killing. Feel free to fork the query, or suggest improvements in the form of a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77638/forgotten-zombie-killers)

Comment: You might want to add that zombie = unanswered question. That might not be clear to everyone.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg right... I did link to the memes page though..

Comment: In the sense of this 'question', I still have a doubt: are 'zombies' unanswered questions?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel [Yes!](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1511/23788)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have 2: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75512/php-mimetype-class and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70098/uintarray-class-in-php-part-2 (both mine). Maybe they are of low quality? Any advice to improve the questions? (I won't use bounties anymore. Last time I used one, it fell in waste)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, you might also consider self-answering your question if you have already made some improvements by yourself. I did so with [one of mine](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83490/an-intrusive-chained-hash-table/84516#84516) very recently.

Comment: @glampert I know, but if I had any improvement to make, I wouldn't leave the questions unanswered. Specially the 2nd. I even gave a bounty of 100!

Comment: @Vogel612 added what I could get from the [Site Activity](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph) SEDE query. The numbers are indeed in a completely different ball park.

Comment: Does the number of zombies include the closed questions? It seems that there has been a number of closed questions these days compared to some months ago.

Comment: I don't quite get why I see questions with accepted answers [using the search](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1..+lastactive%3A..8d+isanswered%3A0)