# Blockquotes and formatting

Tags: discussion, editing, formatting

In [many](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/63477/23788), [many](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/64214/23788), [many](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62709/23788), [many](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57889/23788) or my recent questions, I've [mis]used blockquotes to separate code files.

I always do it like this:

> **Identifier** type of code file

As in

> **Foo** class

and

> **IFoo** interface

I find it makes prettier headings than "normal" headings do, like

#### Foo class

and

#### IFoo interface

..especially with the nice little yellow background for these blocks on the main site, and I like that I can put **bold** and non-emphasized text on the same line.

---

A recent question contained a number of classes, all in the same code block - so in order to reduce the vertical scrolling I edited the post to separate the classes involved, and introduced my usual blockquote formatting. But then [it was removed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/64943/revisions).

> *Fixed improper use of blockquotes*

<sub>^^ note: proper use of blockquotes ;)</sub>

Since the OP posted a [follow-up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/65024/23788) and seemingly adopted my suggested formatting, should the blockquotes be edited out?

I will refrain from editing this formatting into other people's posts (I don't think I've done it before), but should I stop doing that with my own posts? Should my questions' formatting be edited to remove the improper use of blockquotes?

Comment: Somewhat related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240694/197901

Comment: One option would be, without using block quotes, to keep said emphasis, would be to write it like `#**Foo** class`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use blockquotes for blockquotes.  Use headers for headers.  There is no guarantee that blockquotes will look like nice headers on all Stack Exchange interfaces, including the desktop, mobile, and Android/iOS apps.  Furthermore, we expect the site to be redesigned soon for graduation, and blockquote rendering may change.

In fact, now might be a good time to [make a suggestion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like) for how headers should be rendered in the new site design.