# what should our slogan be?

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

In addition of the [logo question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like) I would raise the same question for a slogan.
Give in one strong sentence the real meaning of our lovely CR community.

One of the things the sentence could contain :

- What we do for you.
- How we work.
- We don't discriminate.
- We vote a lot for good questions and answers.
- We do have **[the best chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)**.

I don't think a lot of sister sites do have a slogan, but remember **CR is unique** so we deserve unique things.

Answer (score 1):

Proposal :

> Improving code, habits and people with a smile.

Comment: That's discriminatory: we're only improving people with a smile! what of all the people without one?